# Sort chat conversation in Pandas

Tags: pandas, sorting, group-by

I have a dataset of chat conversations that looks like this (where the `message_id` is an index for all of the messages in the database).:

```
| message_id | to_user | from_user | message      |
|------------|---------|-----------|--------------|
| 123        | al      | sal       | hi           |
| 871        | al      | hal       | hey          |
| 989        | al      | bob       | me too       |
| 900        | sal     | sal       | hello        |
| 107        | bob     | al        | i'm bob      |
| 242        | sal     | al        | how are you? |
| 101        | al      | bob       | hi, i'm al   |
| 898        | sal     | al        | i'm good     |
```

What I want to do is sort this table to reflect a conversation between two people. So it would first group all of the conversations from `to_user` and each `from_user` that they chatted with, and then for each conversation between a `to_user` and `from_user` sort them by their message_id so it would reflect the back and forth conversation.

```
| message_id | to_user | from_user | message      |
|------------|---------|-----------|--------------|
| 101        | al      | bob       | hi, i'm al   |
| 107        | bob     | al        | i'm bob      |
| 989        | al      | bob       | me too       |
| 123        | al      | sal       | hi           |
| 242        | sal     | al        | how are you? |
| 871        | al      | sal       | hey          |
| 898        | sal     | al        | i'm good     |
| 900        | sal     | al        | hello        |
```

How would I accomplish this in Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`np.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) to sort values across rows so that we have columns that specify the participants, but not direction, then sort by conversation and message id with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df[['person_a', 'person_b']] = np.sort(df[['to_user', 'from_user']])
df = df.sort_values(['message_id', 'person_a', 'person_b'], ignore_index=True)
```

```
   message_id to_user from_user       message person_a person_b
0         101      al       bob    hi, i'm al       al      bob
1         107     bob        al       i'm bob       al      bob
2         989      al       bob        me too       al      bob
3         123      al       sal            hi       al      sal
4         242     sal        al  how are you?       al      sal
5         871      al       sal           hey       al      sal
6         898     sal        al      i'm good       al      sal
7         900     sal        al         hello       al      sal
```

---

We can [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) these additional columns after we're done with them:

```
df[['person_a', 'person_b']] = np.sort(df[['to_user', 'from_user']])
df = df.sort_values(
    ['message_id', 'person_a', 'person_b'], ignore_index=True
).drop(columns=['person_a', 'person_b'])
```

`df`:

```
   message_id to_user from_user       message
0         101      al       bob    hi, i'm al
1         107     bob        al       i'm bob
2         989      al       bob        me too
3         123      al       sal            hi
4         242     sal        al  how are you?
5         871      al       sal           hey
6         898     sal        al      i'm good
7         900     sal        al         hello
```

---

Setup and imports (edited to match output):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'message_id': [123, 871, 989, 900, 107, 242, 101, 898],
    'to_user': ['al', 'al', 'al', 'sal', 'bob', 'sal', 'al', 'sal'],
    'from_user': ['sal', 'sal', 'bob', 'al', 'al', 'al', 'bob', 'al'],
    'message': ['hi', 'hey', 'me too', 'hello', "i'm bob", 'how are you?',
                "hi, i'm al", "i'm good"]
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm getting the following error for the line: `df[['person_a', 'person_b']] = np.sort(df[['to_user', 'from_user']])` 
error:`KeyError: "None of [Index(['person_a', 'person_b'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]" 
`

Comment: Hm... that's odd. `['person_a', 'person_b']` is a list. Not an index. Also that's assignment not selection.... so it wouldn't do a column check.